# Why I am getting Runtime Time error when I am trying to submit this code on competitive programming platform?

Tags: java

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
           int t=sc.nextInt();
        while(t-->0){
          int n=sc.nextInt();
          int k=sc.nextInt();
          int[] arr=new int[n];
          for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
          }
          rotation(0,n-k-1,arr);
           rotation(n-k,n-1,arr);
        // rotation(0,n-1,arr);
          int temp;
          for(int i=n-1,j=0;j<i;i--,j++)
          {
             temp=arr[j];
             arr[j]=arr[i];
             arr[i]=temp;
          }
         // for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         //  System.out.print(arr[i]);
         //  System.out.print(" ");
         // }
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
         
        }
        }
        public static void rotation(int start,int end,int[] arr)
        {
          int temp;
          for(int i=end,j=start;j<i;i--,j++)
          {
             temp=arr[start];
             arr[start]=arr[end];
             arr[end]=temp;
          }
          
          
        }
      

    }
```

These are the constraints to be taken care of
1<=T<=20

1<=N<=10^5

0<=K<=10^6

0<=A[i]<=10^6

Input Format:
The first line contains an integer
T
denoting the number of test cases.
Each test case consists of two lines.
The first line contains
N
, number of elements in the array and
K
number of steps.
The Second line contains
N
space-separated integers.

Output Format:For each test case on a new line, print the rotated array.

Comment: Specifying the language with a tag is useful, that way people who care about [tag:java] will see it. That said, what is the _specific error_ you get? Because when I run it, I get `cannot find symbol Scanner sc=new Scanner` because you're missing an import. Maybe that's the problem, or maybe it's just because you didn't paste it into the question... please click edit on your question and add details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code doesn't compile.
Look at the compiler errors:

```
Main.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class IOException
  location: class Main
Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
      ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class Main
Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
                     ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class Main
Main.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
                            ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class Main
4 errors
error: compilation failed
```

What does `cannot find symbol` mean? In this case it means, the compiler doesn't know, what `Scanner`, `IOException` and `Arrays` are.
You have to import these classes:
Add following before `public class Main`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Now you should be able to compile the code.

Comment: I have included the imports and my program gives correct output. The problem is when I try to submit my code on the coding platform it's giving me a runtime time error message and it's not accepting my code. Whereas when I execute the code on my machine I am not getting any such error and output is correct.

Comment: What is the "runtime time error message"?

Answer (score -2):

May be changing the class name will execute this code.bcoz I think "Main" is keyword and we can't use it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a useful answer (and it's incorrect) and is better suited to being a comment. When you have enough reputation, you'll be able to post comments. Thanks.

Comment: Having a class called `Main` is completely legal.